# What causes react proptype error and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am getting this error (see picture) even though I have prop type validation setup. Its making debugging anything else a nightmare as every time any state changes it outputs these messages

```
import { makeMoveStr } from "./tour";

function CompletedPanel({ tour, impossible }) {
    if (
        impossible ||
        (tour.visited.length !== 64 && tour.validMoves.length === 0)
    ) {
        return <h2>Could not find a tour from this position try again.</h2>;
    } else if (tour.completed === null) {
        return <h2>Tour is not completed</h2>;
    } else if (tour.completed.visited.length === 64) {
        return <p>{makeMoveStr(tour.completed.visitedStr)}</p>;
    }
}

CompletedPanel.propTypes = {
    tour: Object,
    impossible: Boolean,
};

export default CompletedPanel;
```

[image: Console warning]

A google search yielded no solution that made it go away.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
CompletedPanel.propTypes = {
    tour: PropTypes.object,
    impossible: PropTypes.bool,
};
```